# my macbook does not recognise the hard disk

Tags: macos, usb, external-disk

I have plugged in the hard disk in my macbook, and the hard disk's led has turned on. Nevertheless I cannot see the hard disk anywhere. I tried with `df -h` and `lsusb`but none of them give a difference when the hard disk is plugged in and when is not.
The only difference is when I run `sudo dmesg | tail`. When the hard disk is plugged I get:

```
Tommasos-MBP:dev tommaso$ sudo dmesg | tail
ARPT: 1724.609440: ACK 0 IM 0 PM 1 Suppr 0 (None)
ARPT: 1724.609447: CNT(rts_tx)=0 CNT(frag_tx_cnt)=15 CNT(cts_rx_cnt)=0
ARPT: 1724.609453: DequeueTime: 0xfd79a000 LastTxTime: 0x65fc468e PHYTxErr:   0x0000 RxAckRSSI: 0x0000 RxAckSQ: 0x0000
ARPT: 1724.609475: Raw[0]    1 Valid
ARPT: 1724.609482: [2]    0 IM
ARPT: 1724.609486: [3]    1 PM
ARPT: 1724.609490: [7-4]  0 Suppr
ARPT: 1724.609494: [14:8] 1 Ncons
ARPT: 1724.609499: [15]   0 Acked
ARPT: 1724.609504: txpktpend AC_BK 0 AC_BE 0 AC_VI 0 AC_VO 1 BCMC 0 ATIM 0
```

When it is not plugged I get:

```
ARPT: 1769.348943: [3]    1 PM
ARPT: 1769.348947: [7-4]  0 Suppr
ARPT: 1769.348952: [14:8] 1 Ncons
ARPT: 1769.348956: [15]   0 Acked
ARPT: 1769.348961: txpktpend AC_BK 0 AC_BE 0 AC_VI 0 AC_VO 1 BCMC 0 ATIM 0
sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: pid 389 responsible for 389sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed from cache for pid 389: not approvedsb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar for CalendarAgent [389]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceCalendar satisifed by entitlement for pid 3891777025331us AppleThunderboltGenericHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 0 milliseconds
AppleThunderboltGenericHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 0 milliseconds
IOThunderboltSwitch<0>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 9 unplug = 0
IOThunderboltSwitch<0>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 10 unplug = 0
sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for mds [78]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 78sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 539sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles for CoreServicesUIAg [539]sb_user_approval: kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAllFiles satisifed by entitlement for pid 53
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is to scan any device, so look for a `fsck` process if you see the hardware device but no mount. Many disk recovery tools will suppress this so you might try those as well.

- Does `diskutil list` show the device?
- Does it show up in `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`?
- How exactly is the disk connected?